# How do I find out why gdb has stopped

Tags: c++, gdb

While using GDB to debug a program I have been having issues with the program stopping while in debug mode.  When I do a backtrace, I find that it's deep within a proprietary third party library call stack and I am looking to find out why exactly the program has stopped.  I am still just a GDB beginner so I still unsure of how to do this.  Looking at the backtrace I noticed that "__cxa_throw () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6" so I am presuming that an exception of some sort was thrown but I would like to know how to get more information about it, if possible.

Comment: The gdb "up" command lets you shift focus one level higher on the call stack. If you move up to a point prior to the exception where your code exists, you can see what you were doing at the time (and hopefully determine if you're calling a function with bad data).

Comment: I did so and everything in my code seems good (at least according to their documentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I find out why gdb has stopped

GDB usually tells you right away, e.g.

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7750425 in __GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>)
```

The program stopped because it received a signal.

> I find that it's deep within a proprietary third party library call stack and I am looking to find out why exactly the program has stopped.

It has stopped *exactly* for the reason GDB told you about.

> Looking at the backtrace I noticed that `__cxa_throw() from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` so I am presuming that an exception of some sort was thrown but I would like to know how to get more information about it.

Presence of `__cxa_throw` does indicate that an exception has been thrown (and presence of `std::terminate()` indicates that it was an uncaught exception).

Without debug info for the third-party library, your choices of finding the cause are limited:

- You can read the documentation for this library and double-check that you have not violated any preconditions that it requires
- You can disassemble the routine that called `__cxa_throw` and figure out exactly why that routine was called.

Comment: How can I make `gdb` tell me again the stop message/reason `Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted`? I had switched between `"Ctrl+X", "Ctrl+A"` and when I got back, `gdb` had lost that initial message along with others.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `backtrace` command which will show how your program got in the state it is. [Here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_42.html) you can find more details.

Comment: I tried that and it lead me to where an exception was thrown, but not why.  It would not surprise me if the answer to "why" is not available but here is for hoping.

Comment: hm. I usually then jump to a frame, because I have an idea what might have caused the problem. Are you able to see the source code in the specific frame with the `list` command? Are you sure that the code you are debugging was compiled with  `-ggdb -DFULLDEBUG -O0` options?

Comment: Actually I can confidently say that the third party libraries I have where NOT built with any debugging information.  *sigh*

Comment: @Brian: the only way to see the info, that I know of, is to recompile the library with debug flags.